# Visual Studio 2017 Breakpoint Xamarin

Tags: debugging, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio Profesional 2017 .

Version: 15.1 (26403.3) Release

Xamarin Portable library and UWP Project (not tested with Android), target to "Localhost" (Windows 10 Aniversary)

Since last update of Visual Studio (updated yesterday), break points doesn't work on an existing project, not work in Portable library and not work in UWP Project. Project was working fine before last VS2017 update, and yesterday after work with Project, i installed last update from VS2017 notification center.

I deleted all bin/obj folders, Clean Project and Rebuild solution, doesn't solve problem.

I've created a new Project with default settings (Master detail/Portable library) and in new project breakpoint Works in UWP Project, at least in MainPage.cs->MainPage() -> LoadApplication(new App3.App()) line. But doesn't work well with some parts of Portable library code, as you can see in picture.

[image].

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried deleting all your breakpoints ? Debug->Delete All Breakpoints.   If all else fails, what about deleting your .suo file.

Comment: Yes, i had tried it, i too deleted .user files, and doesn't work.

Comment: Time to return to System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine....Wow!!!....disaster, and frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i solved it, i not very sure how, but i did it, i recover a project backup, and with Winmerge, i compared all .csproj, .csproj.user, .nutget, nutget.targets files (I've replaced all the lines, I thought it appropriate from backup Project, because i created a new Project and i've been adding everything back from scratch)

I try many things, but my lasts steps:

-In UWP Project:

- .csproj.user: delete all lines, and now i only have : ShowAllFiles
- .csproject: change TargetPlatformMinVersion, to lowest. Add reference: Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=14.0

-In Portable library:

- .csproj: Delete line "AllowUnsafeBlocks"
- .csproj.user: Delete all lines, and replace with :  ProjectView: ShowAllFiles

And finally, but not least, I've updated Xamarin.forms in all projects to version 2.3.4.231

Really, when i can do work breakpoint has been when i added Microsoft.VCLibs, and update Xamarin.Forms nutget, i do this two steeps at same time, and then works.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are having this problem with a Xamarin.Forms project that is either just updated from PCL to .Net Standard, or just created new as a .Net Standard:

1. Right click on your .Net Standard proj -> Properties
2. Build Tab -> Advanced... button
3. Switch Debugging Information combo box from "Portable" to "Full"

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it:

Right click on your Android project -> Properties -> Build -> Uncheck "Optimize Code".

And Android project -> Properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Debugging information -> set it to "Full".